# Linearization of IR sensor GP2Y0A21YK

Tags: voltage, infrared, distance, non-linear

How do I linearize the graph analog output voltage against distance for IR sensor [GP2Y0A21YK][1]?

This is the non- linear graph, I’m not sure how to make it linear?
  [1]: https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Sharp%20PDFs/GP2Y0A21YK.pdf[image][image]

Comment: Which graph? Why? At which point? What have you tried so far, where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: This is a homework-style question, and you're not demonstrating any own consideration so far – which makes it practically impossible to answer other than just repeating the definition of linearization, which probably won't help you. You need to explain where exactly you're stuck, and what you've tried so far!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I don't think it's homework but shows no sign of any prior efforts, though. So we must deal with the math basics here.

Comment: @Ariser-reinstateMonica previous question was "How to interface 8 of this exact same sensor to a comparator, I'm not allowed to use an Arduino (and later: also not any other microcontroller)"; this sounds *very* much like a school assignment.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Ok, didn't notice that. Sounds plausible.

Comment: Yeah it’s a design project and then I need to simulate it on multism

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You will note that there are two possible distances for voltages above 400mV to 3.15V or so.

So you will have to decide which curve you want to use (it's not possible to tell which it is from the voltage alone).

Then fit a function to the given points. You can pull the data directly from the pdf with WebPlotDigitizer or a similar method, and use MATLAB to fit a polynomial or do it manually or with Scilab etc. using least squares error for example. Even Excel can be used. Or just use the points they've given you and use linear interpolation or cubic splines if you want to get fancy.

Comment: @Tukoor you measure 1.5V. Does that mean your distance is ca 2.5cm or ca 17cm? you can't tell – the function is not invertible.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany can I use an log amplifier to linearize it?

Comment: I would use an MCU with a 12-bit ADC and linearize it digitally. 12-bit rather than 10 because the resolution would otherwise be a bit coarse at larger distances. But you can see if a log curve fits, and how well, and compare error with your requirements.

Comment: I can’t use an MCU

Comment: If it's a homework problem with artificial constraints that provides a learning opportunity and I would not want to deprive you of the satisfaction of coming up with a working solution.